# jQuery.click(): Can I get a reference to the synthetic event object passed to event handlers?

Tags: onclick, jquery

I have an `<a>` inside a `<TD>`, and I'm trying to have clicks on the `<TD>`, but outside the `<A>`, act like they were clicks on the `<a>`.  I'm almost there:

HTML:

```
<TD class="somethingPretty">
    <a href="someURL" class="anchor">Text</a>
</td>
```

JS:

```
$('.anchor').click(function(ev){return confirm("go ahead?");});
$('somethingPretty').click(function(ev){
    if($('.anchor').click()){
        document.location = $('.anchor').attr('href');
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that `jQuery.click` returns `undefined`, and I can't see how to get at the event object that's passed to the click handlers so I can interrogate it with `isPropagationStopped` and `isDefaultPrevented`. What's the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: I should point out, I am also stopping propagation on clicks to the <a>, so they don't bubble up and trigger the TD ones as well.

Comment: Is there a reason not to bind everything to the TD and nothing to the A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes asking the question clearly is the best way to find an answer.  Some strategic poking around the jQuery source led me to the following solution(using the markup above):

```
$('.somethingPretty').click(function(ev){
    var syntheticClick = new $.Event("click");
    syntheticClick.stopPropagation();
    $('.anchor').trigger(syntheticClick);
    if(syntheticClick.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
    document.location = $('.anchor').attr('href');
}
```

This works for all event handlers except live-bound ones (those don't execute; my users will have to learn to click the anchor itself for them!).  The tricky part here is that `trigger` takes a `jQuery.Event` in addition to the documented string.

Comment: I think that this trick could also be good for debugging to find out what piece of code is calling preventDefault() or stopPropagation(): `var event = new $.Event("click"); event.preventDefault = function() { debugger; }; event.stopPropagation = function() { debugger; }; $('.anchor').trigger(event);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var a = $('.somethingPretty .anchor');
var td = $('.somethingPretty');

a.click( function(ev) { return confirm("go ahead?"); } );
td.click( function() { a.click(); } );
```

Comment: This doesn't cause document.location to change.

Comment: No, I didn't write all of the code for you. But I did give you what should be a functional base you could understand and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
$("td.outer").add("td.outer a").click(function() { 
   // do stuff
});
```

You're going to want to find some way to ensure that whatever is in the function runs only once, since a click on the `<a>` will count both as a click on the `<td>` and the `<a>`.